# Optimizing Large Vector Graphics Animation in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, optimization, vector

I've done a few flash games in the past, all of which are very intensive on the animation. I've realized that having bigger animated object (which are each made up by ~20 vector graphics components) on the screen reduces frame rate drastically. Now I want to make a game where the camera can zoom in and out of particular parts of the object, but this necessarily means that the object itself will likely be enlarged so much that the animation stalls. Is there a smart solution to this?

I'm already using and reusing lots of symbols, due to customization I'd rather keep the individual components apart instead of merging them into a single svg for each frame. I can certainly optimize the actual graphics more (about 50% for every component), but I'm wondering how big of an effect this has on increasing performance. On average, I'd have 20-40 of these components on the screen moving at (hopefully) 24 fps.

Thanks!

Comment: make the vectors as uncomplicated as possible.  Cache them as bitmap when you can,  and export with GPU accelleration (for the cached as bitmap vectors sake).

Comment: Try using Adobe Scout to profile your application to find out whether it's the vector drawing that takes the most time to complete each frame, if yes, then that "about 50%" graphics optimization will cut about 40% (YMMV!) time spent on drawing. If not the graphics is the main time hog, then optimize that part first. LDMS is right to suggest cache-as-bitmap optimization, you can even pre-draw your vectors at runtime to create a sprite sheet or a bitmap set to be used afterwards.

Comment: cacheasbitmap can make matter worst in movieclip animation since it's most efficient on a per symbol basis and not really when applied to an entire mc + that efficienty goes away if the symbol rotate or are scaled etc ... The best solution is to reduce complexity of vector and introduce inside symbol bitmaps for simple parts. Better yet make two versions of those symbol, one with only bitmap (the normal sized symbol) and one with vector (the one used for zooming) and switch between them when needed.

Comment: cacheAsBitmap is not usable with rotations and scaling.Better control the FOV. Use a Mask for the visible area. Take control about what is visible and what you dont't need at every moment.